# How to transfer my data from MS ACCESS DB to a new SQL SERVER DB?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a **contact DB** that I created 3 years ago in MS ACCESS. After 1 year learning ASP.NET/C#, I'm comfortable witting application now for my office. So, I would like to create the same application in web (using ASP.NET/C#/SQL SERVER) so that anybody in my department can access. Meanwhile, there are at least 127 contacts, preventing me from just start **a new DB** from scratch.

So, those are my questions:

Is is a way I can transfer my data from the **ACCESS DB** to the **SQL SERVER DB**? 
Should I write a small application that read data from the ACCESS file and write it to my new SQL SERVER DB?
Is there a software that can do that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe that this question belongs on `ServerFault.com`

Comment: I'm really sorry. I really didn't know that I have to do that. However, I was wondering why some answers have numbers next to them. I'll read all the resources related to good behaviors in stackOverflow. I did not want to sound impolite. I'm so grateful about all the prompt and usefull answers I get here.

Thanks, one more time for letting me know.
Ric

Comment: Sung.  I disagree.  I feel this is a developers question.

Comment: It's unquestionably a developer's question.

Comment: *Real* developers don't use wizards ;)

Comment: A real developer will use a wizard if it is faster than writing the code from scratch and the code produced does not need to be substantially altered. Same with SQL. The find unmatched wizard is a lot easier than writing the same SQL by hand or using the QBE. All that said, I don't use many wizards.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "Look for Smileys, grins, and other 'Emoticons'. When you see one, the preceding statement was not meant to be really serious, don't take it as such."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has an upsizing wizard specifically for this purpose.  It's not perfect but it is quick and dirty if that is what you're after.  Some links before you get started:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237980

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325017

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/10things/?p=391

http://web.archive.org/web/20080823140515/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-upsize-from-access-to-sql-server.html

Comment: We Access folks are recommending the SSMA tool as it does a better job than the upszing wizards that come with Access. SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA Access)
http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tony, been a LOOOONG time since I used Access, didn't know about SSMA.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Management Studio, there is an "Import" wizard that will whisk the data into your new database for you.

Microsoft have a KB article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Apologies - the above article is indeed for Excel - the Access version is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250616/en-us

Comment: That KB article is for importing Excel data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server hat an import and export tool. Take a look at this.